# Automatic calculation of variable prices for woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I,m creating an ecommerce website. I have products with different options. Currently what I can do is I can I can set the attributes and then I need to link them and enter prices for every variation separately . Which is almost impossible because I have so many options. Is there any option so that I can keep a base price and customer can add additional options to them. And woocommerce automatically calculate the price ? And I only need to add price for base price and different options ?

I can use gravity forms addon to achieve this but gravity form doesn't display the additional details in order detail page. I need to navigate to gravity form entry to check the additional options for an order. Which is impossible also to track an order's additional options. And CSV import suite also can't import gravity form fields . Can Anyone help please ?

Base Price: $25
Size
- Small: add $0
- Medium: add $15
- Large: add $20
Color
- Blue: add $0
- Green: add $10
- Purple: add $25

Price = 1 +2 +3

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the [Gravity Forms Add-ons](http://www.woothemes.com/products/gravity-forms-add-ons/). Basically you connect your item and your Gravity Form. With the Gravity Form you can customize the variables and prices.

Example forms (which you can download and import into your own WordPress): [Pizza Builder](http://www.gravityforms.com/demo/build-a-pizza/)

Hope this helps you.